# In an STL Map of structs, why does the "[ ]" operator cause the struct's dtor to be invoked 2 extra times?

Tags: c++, stl, constructor, copy-constructor, temporary-objects

I've created a simple test case exhibiting a strange behavior I've noticed in a larger code base I'm working on. This test case is below. I'm relying on the STL Map's "[ ]" operator to create a pointer to a struct in a map of such structs. In the test case below, the line...

```
TestStruct *thisTestStruct = &testStructMap["test"];
```

...gets me the pointer (and creates a new entry in the map). The weird thing I've noticed is that this line not only causes a new entry in the map to be created (because of the "[ ]" operator), but for some reason it causes the struct's destructor to be called two extra times. I'm obviously missing something - any help is much appreciated! 
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
struct TestStruct;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

    map<string, TestStruct> testStructMap;

    std::cout << "Marker One\n";

    //why does this line cause "~TestStruct()" to be invoked twice?
    TestStruct *thisTestStruct = &testStructMap["test"];

    std::cout << "Marker Two\n";

    return 0;
}

struct TestStruct{
    TestStruct(){
        std::cout << "TestStruct Constructor!\n";
    }

    ~TestStruct(){
        std::cout << "TestStruct Destructor!\n";
    }
};
```

the code above outputs the following...

```
/*
Marker One
TestStruct Constructor!             //makes sense
TestStruct Destructor!               //<---why?
TestStruct Destructor!               //<---god why?
Marker Two
TestStruct Destructor!               //makes sense
*/
```

...but I don't understand what causes the first two invocations of TestStruct's destructor? 
(I think the last destructor invocation makes sense because testStructMap is going out of scope.)

Comment: The answer is below. But turn the optimization level as high as it will go and see how many copies get elided.

Comment: Further details about this question and the why behind it may be found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021118/why-doesnt-c-stdmapoperator-use-inplace-new

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The functionality of `std::map<>::operator[]` is equivalent to

```
(*((std::map<>::insert(std::make_pair(x, T()))).first)).second
```

expression, as specified in the language specification. This, as you can see, involves default-constructing a temporary object of type `T`, copying it into a `std::pair` object, which is later copied (again) into the new element of the map (assuming it wasn't there already). Obviously, this will produce a few intermediate `T` objects. Destruction of these intermediate objects is what you observe in your experiment. You miss their construction, since you don't generate any feedback from copy-constructor of your class.

The exact number of intermediate objects might depend on compiler optimization capabilities, so the results may vary.

Answer (score 8):

You have some unseen copies being made:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
struct TestStruct;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

    map<string, TestStruct> testStructMap;

    std::cout << "Marker One\n";

    //why does this line cause "~TestStruct()" to be invoked twice?
    TestStruct *thisTestStruct = &testStructMap["test"];

    std::cout << "Marker Two\n";

    return 0;
}

struct TestStruct{
    TestStruct(){
        std::cout << "TestStruct Constructor!\n";
    }

    TestStruct( TestStruct const& other) {
        std::cout << "TestStruct copy Constructor!\n";
    }

    TestStruct& operator=( TestStruct const& rhs) {
        std::cout << "TestStruct copy assignment!\n";
    }

    ~TestStruct(){
        std::cout << "TestStruct Destructor!\n";
    }
};
```

Results in:

```
Marker One
TestStruct Constructor!
TestStruct copy Constructor!
TestStruct copy Constructor!
TestStruct Destructor!
TestStruct Destructor!
Marker Two
TestStruct Destructor!
```

Answer (score 5):

add the following to TestStruct's interface:

```
TestStruct(const TestStruct& other) {
    std::cout << "TestStruct Copy Constructor!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`operator[]` inserts to the `map` if there is not already an element there.

What you are missing is output for the compiler-supplied copy constructor in your `TestStruct`, which is used during container housekeeping.  Add that output, and it should all make more sense.

EDIT: Andrey's answer prompted me to take a look at the source in Microsoft VC++ 10's `<map>`, which is something you could also do to follow this through in all its gory detail.  You can see the `insert()` call to which he refers.

```
mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& _Keyval)
    {   // find element matching _Keyval or insert with default mapped
    iterator _Where = this->lower_bound(_Keyval);
    if (_Where == this->end()
        || this->comp(_Keyval, this->_Key(_Where._Mynode())))
        _Where = this->insert(_Where,
            value_type(_Keyval, mapped_type()));
    return ((*_Where).second);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your two mysterious destructor calls are probably paired with copy constructor calls going on somewhere within the `std::map`. For example, it's conceivable that `operator[]` default-constructs a temporary `TestStruct` object, and then copy-constructs it into the proper location in the map. The reason that there are two destructor calls (and thus probably two copy constructor calls) is implementation-specific, and will depend on your compiler and standard library implementation.

Answer (score 0):

so the lesson is - dont put structs in a map if you care about their lifecycles. Use pointers, or even better shared_ptrs to them

Answer (score 0):

You can check it out through this more simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class AA
{
public:
  AA()            { cout << "default const" << endl; }
  AA(int a):x(a)  { cout << "user const" << endl; }
  AA(const AA& a) { cout << "default copy const" << endl; }
  ~AA()           { cout << "dest" << endl; }
private:
  int x;
};

int main ()
{
  AA o1(1);

  std::map<char,AA> mymap;

  mymap['x']=o1;    // (1)

  return 0;
}
```

The below result shows that (1) line code above makes (1 default const) and (2 default copy const) calls.

```
user const
default const        // here
default copy const   // here
default copy const   // here
dest
dest
dest
dest
```