# Why doesn't C++ std::map::operator[] use inplace new?

Tags: c++, stl, new-operator

If you use the C++ std::map (and other containers) with value types, you'll notice that inserting into the map calls the destructor for your element type. This is because the implementation of operator [] is required by the C++ spec to be **equivalent** to this:

```
(*((std::map<>::insert(std::make_pair(x, T()))).first)).second
```

It calls the default constructor of your type in order to build that pair. That temporary value is then copied into the map, and then destructed. Confirmation of this can be found in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017892/in-an-stl-map-of-structs-why-does-the-operator-cause-the-structs-dtor-to) and [here on codeguru](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?481795-map-calling-destructor-twice-when-adding-new-element).

What I find odd is that this could be implemented without the need for the temporary variable and still be equivalent. There is a feature of C++ called ["inplace new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new). The std::map and other containers could allocate empty space for the object to live and then explicitly call the element's default constructor on the allocated space.

**My question:** Why do none of the implementations of std::map that I've seen use inplace new to optimize this operation? It seems to me that it would considerably improve the performance of this low-level operation. But many eyes have studied the STL code base, so I figure there must be some reason it is done this way.

Comment: Test case is included in the linked stackoverflow post. Here's the link again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017892/in-an-stl-map-of-structs-why-does-the-operator-cause-the-structs-dtor-to

Comment: Mike Seymour: So you're suggesting that with the debugger turned off, these extra calls to the destructor would go away? Do you know that's true?  Even if it is true, it does mean that with debugging on, the execution is harder to debug (I can't just set a breakpoint in my debugger looking for "real" scope issues). It is also less performant while debugging, which is a lesser issue, but still real. Both of these reasons would seem to me to be reasons to use the inplace new instead for such a low-level library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you specifying a higher level operation like `[]` in terms of lower level ones is a good idea.

Prior to C++11, doing so with `[]` would be difficult without using `insert`.

In C++11, the addition of `std::map<?>::emplace` and similar stuff for `std::pair` gives us the ability to avoid that problem.  If you redefined it so use such in-place construction, the extra (hopefully elided) object creation would go away.

I cannot think of a reason not do this.  I would encourage you to propose it for standardization.

To demonstrate copy-less insertion into a `std::map`, we can do the following:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct no_copy_type {
  no_copy_type(no_copy_type const&)=delete;
  no_copy_type(double) {}
  ~no_copy_type() { std::cout << "destroyed\n"; }
};
int main() {
  std::map< int, no_copy_type > m;
  m.emplace(
    std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(1),
    std::forward_as_tuple(3.14)
  );
  std::cout << "destroy happens next:\n";
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/mG1iAJ) -- as you can see, no temporary is generated.

So if we replace

```
(*((std::map<>::insert(std::make_pair(x, T()))).first)).second
```

with

```
(*
  (
    (
      std::map<>::emplace(
        std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<X>(x)),
        std::forward_as_tuple()
    )
  ).first
).second
```

no temporary would be created (whitespace added so I could keep track of `()`s).

Comment: The answer earlier from Mike Seymour suggests that the ability of programmers to choose an alternate Allocator means that the construction of the temporary cannot be removed from the code and must be elided during optimization, which is sad both from a debugging standpoint and from explaining to new users why a destructor is invoked during insert.

Comment: @srm Sure.  But Mike is wrong.  It is a minor defect (inefficiency) in the standard, assuming it wasn't already fixed (I didn't check the latest).  Allocators can be rebound, and emplace and piecewise construction can let you construct the object without any temporary.  Default construction can be done via an empty `tuple`.

Comment: I don't know enough to comment. That's why I asked the question. Can you post your comment onto Mike's answer so he gets notification and see if you two can convince one another?

Answer (score 0):

First off, `operator[<key>]` for `std::map` is only equivalent to an insert operation *if* the requested `<key>` is not found. In this case, only a reference to the key is needed and only a reference to the stored value produced.

Second, when the new element is inserted there is no way of knowing if a copy operation will follow. You might have `map[_k] = _v;`, or you might have `_v = map[_k];`. The latter of course has the same requirements as it does outside of an assignment, i.e. `map[_k].method_call();`, but does **not** use the copy constructor (theres's no source to construct from). Regarding insertion, all of the above require that the default constructor of the `value_type` be called and that space be allocated for it. Even if we could know when writing `operator[]` that we were in the assignment use-case, we could not use "inplace new" because of the order of operations. The `value_type` constructor would have to be called first, followed by `value_type::operator=`, which necessitates the calling of the copy constructor.

Nice thinking though.